# Mosaic hillshade function does not save statistics/histograms in ArcMap 10.2.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, windows-8, hillshade

I used ArcGIS 10.2.1. on Windows 8. I did hillshade function for DEM and *Calculate statistics*. Every time I go into ArcMap statistics strays:

[image]

I try to add this function on mosaic but didn't worked.

[image]

I try turn off/on *Enable* Geoprocessing and again didn't worked...
Any ideas how I can "keep" it for function?
Thanks.

Comment: I have been observing this bug too since at least 10.1.

Comment: It's bug? Can this be fixed?

Comment: Good question, I will be curious to see what the consensus is.

Comment: Strange, it keeps statistics if I choose Standard Deviation. Earlier it was not possible to keep. Maybe it's bug of Windows 8 access. I check the access to folder C:\Users\2E78~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arcE5BA\ and ArcGIS account have full permissions, i try re access and worked now.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. But not stored in the mosaic ...How can I do this for a mosaic?

Comment: And why i can't publish raster hillsahde function on server? ERROR 001369: Failed to create the service